# Assistance needed with moving code out of sharedPreference

Tags: android

I have an alertDialog that uses shared preference so the dialog can only be displayed once. Some of you may know that it caused my activity to behave funny and by I mean by not responding to the onClick of my button. I was told to move the bottom half of my activity which starts after `alert.show();`, out the `if` statement of the shared preference which is `if (!initialDialogDisplayed) {` The issue I have is that I do not know where to move the bottom half of my activity to. I do not know if I should move

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  Button getAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            getAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

above shared preference or what. So I am hoping somebody can really assist me with this issue.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean initialDialogDisplayed = preferences.getBoolean("InitialDialog", false);
    if (!initialDialogDisplayed) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("InitialDialog", true);
        editor.commit();


final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Dialog");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
         });

        alertDialog.show();
                final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                Button getAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                getAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {       
                        if (et.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't Be Blank!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             

                        }else{
                            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                            String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();         
                            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
                            in.putExtra("TAG_SEARCH", searchTerm);
                            startActivity(in);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
         }


        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();
        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to move the end bracket for the `if (!initialDialogDisplayed)` if block up further, so that the button `OnClickListener` is set every time `onCreate` is called, not only if `!initialDialogDisplayed`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean initialDialogDisplayed = preferences.getBoolean("InitialDialog", false);
if (!initialDialogDisplayed) {
    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("InitialDialog", true);
    editor.commit();


final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Dialog");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
     });

    alertDialog.show();


    }  //XXX finish the if block here, so that our OnClickListener is set


            final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Button getAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            getAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {       
                    if (et.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't Be Blank!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             

                    }else{
                        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();         
                        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
                        in.putExtra("TAG_SEARCH", searchTerm);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }

                }
            });
        // }  // don't finish if block here
     }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on the current issue you are having or what you want but if you want the `Button` and `EditText` code to run regardless of the value of `initialDialogDisplayed` then move this code

```
 final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Button getAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            getAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {       
                    if (et.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't Be Blank!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             

                    }else{
                        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();         
                        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
                        in.putExtra("TAG_SEARCH", searchTerm);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }

                }
            });
```

directly under

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```